# input doesnt display value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="secound-kreab" placeholder="Twitter name" name="WebsitesAndSocial[]" value="europarl.com">
```

Rendered by:

```
{this.state.Contact.WebsitesAndSocial.map((WebSocial, Index) => {
            return (
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m4 l4">
                  <label htmlFor=""><i className="material-icons">language</i> Websites & Other Links: </label>
                  <input id="secound-kreab" type="text" placeholder="Twitter name" name="WebsitesAndSocial[]" defaultValue={WebSocial} />
                </div>
                {Index == 0 ?
                <div id="add-web" className="add-web btn-floating kreab-color" onClick={this.addWeb} >
                  <i className="material-icons">add</i>
                </div>
                : null}
              </div>
            )
          })}
```

But the browser dosn't display de "value" prop of the  tag.

[dosnt render the value prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjc33.png)

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue using jsfiddle.net?